# Import error with OPENCV in Python on M1 Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, importerror, apple-m1

I'm trying to use OpenCV with Python but I'm continuously getting errors while importing. I'm using Anaconda virtual env and ZSH on Mac M1.
I have tried installing it using
`conda install -c anaconda opencv`
and `pip3 install opencv-python`
but I'm getting this error:

`from .cv2 import * ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib' (no such file)`

Comment: Looks to me like it needs ffmpeg installed.

Comment: Also, you may want to review specific instructions regarding ffmpeg on m1: https://ffmpegfromzerotohero.com/blog/compile-ffmpeg-for-apple-m1-silicon/

Comment: opencv doesn't work on m1 perfectly yet. I solved the error simply by using Anaconda instead of native python distribution.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure that ffmpeg is installed.

for me the issue was that the ffmpeg which I had installed by brew was named like ffmpeg@4 in opt/homebrew/opt/ so it couldn't find it.

I renamed the folder to ffmpeg and the issue was fixed.